# Need help understanding Makefile in xv6

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, kernel, xv6

I have been reading the makefile of xv6 project. I want to put all the user programs into a folder to keep the project tidy. I can not find where it compiles the user programs. I know that when i run: make fs.img; it will compile the user programs, but i can not find any commands to do so. I also want all the kernel code to go into a directory called "kernel".
Is there a feature in make that allows automatic compilation or is there just something I'm not seeing. And could anyone suggest any make docs to help me understand this makefile.

My Makefile:

```
OBJS = \
    bio.o\
    console.o\
    exec.o\
    file.o\
    fs.o\
    ide.o\
    ioapic.o\
    kalloc.o\
    kbd.o\
    lapic.o\
    log.o\
    main.o\
    mp.o\
    picirq.o\
    pipe.o\
    proc.o\
    sleeplock.o\
    spinlock.o\
    string.o\
    swtch.o\
    syscall.o\
    sysfile.o\
    sysproc.o\
    trapasm.o\
    trap.o\
    uart.o\
    vectors.o\
    vm.o\

# Cross-compiling (e.g., on Mac OS X)
# TOOLPREFIX = i386-jos-elf

# Using native tools (e.g., on X86 Linux)
#TOOLPREFIX = 

# Try to infer the correct TOOLPREFIX if not set
ifndef TOOLPREFIX
TOOLPREFIX := $(shell if i386-jos-elf-objdump -i 2>&1 | grep '^elf32-i386$$' >/dev/null 2>&1; \
    then echo 'i386-jos-elf-'; \
    elif objdump -i 2>&1 | grep 'elf32-i386' >/dev/null 2>&1; \
    then echo ''; \
    else echo "***" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** Error: Couldn't find an i386-*-elf version of GCC/binutils." 1>&2; \
    echo "*** Is the directory with i386-jos-elf-gcc in your PATH?" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** If your i386-*-elf toolchain is installed with a command" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** prefix other than 'i386-jos-elf-', set your TOOLPREFIX" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** environment variable to that prefix and run 'make' again." 1>&2; \
    echo "*** To turn off this error, run 'gmake TOOLPREFIX= ...'." 1>&2; \
    echo "***" 1>&2; exit 1; fi)
endif

# If the makefile can't find QEMU, specify its path here
# QEMU = qemu-system-i386

# Try to infer the correct QEMU
ifndef QEMU
QEMU = $(shell if which qemu > /dev/null; \
    then echo qemu; exit; \
    elif which qemu-system-i386 > /dev/null; \
    then echo qemu-system-i386; exit; \
    elif which qemu-system-x86_64 > /dev/null; \
    then echo qemu-system-x86_64; exit; \
    else \
    qemu=/Applications/Q.app/Contents/MacOS/i386-softmmu.app/Contents/MacOS/i386-softmmu; \
    if test -x $$qemu; then echo $$qemu; exit; fi; fi; \
    echo "***" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** Error: Couldn't find a working QEMU executable." 1>&2; \
    echo "*** Is the directory containing the qemu binary in your PATH" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** or have you tried setting the QEMU variable in Makefile?" 1>&2; \
    echo "***" 1>&2; exit 1)
endif

CC = $(TOOLPREFIX)gcc
AS = $(TOOLPREFIX)gas
LD = $(TOOLPREFIX)ld
OBJCOPY = $(TOOLPREFIX)objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(TOOLPREFIX)objdump
CFLAGS = -fno-pic -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer
CFLAGS += $(shell $(CC) -fno-stack-protector -E -x c /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo -fno-stack-protector)
ASFLAGS = -m32 -gdwarf-2 -Wa,-divide
# FreeBSD ld wants ``elf_i386_fbsd''
LDFLAGS += -m $(shell $(LD) -V | grep elf_i386 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)

# Disable PIE when possible (for Ubuntu 16.10 toolchain)
ifneq ($(shell $(CC) -dumpspecs 2>/dev/null | grep -e '[^f]no-pie'),)
CFLAGS += -fno-pie -no-pie
endif
ifneq ($(shell $(CC) -dumpspecs 2>/dev/null | grep -e '[^f]nopie'),)
CFLAGS += -fno-pie -nopie
endif

xv6.img: bootblock kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=xv6.img count=10000
    dd if=bootblock of=xv6.img conv=notrunc
    dd if=kernel of=xv6.img seek=1 conv=notrunc
#
xv6memfs.img: bootblock kernelmemfs
    dd if=/dev/zero of=xv6memfs.img count=10000
    dd if=bootblock of=xv6memfs.img conv=notrunc
    dd if=kernelmemfs of=xv6memfs.img seek=1 conv=notrunc
#
bootblock: bootasm.S bootmain.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fno-pic -O -nostdinc -I. -c bootmain.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fno-pic -nostdinc -I. -c bootasm.S
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e start -Ttext 0x7C00 -o bootblock.o bootasm.o bootmain.o
    $(OBJDUMP) -S bootblock.o > bootblock.asm
    $(OBJCOPY) -S -O binary -j .text bootblock.o bootblock
    ./sign.pl bootblock
#
entryother: entryother.S
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fno-pic -nostdinc -I. -c entryother.S
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e start -Ttext 0x7000 -o bootblockother.o entryother.o
    $(OBJCOPY) -S -O binary -j .text bootblockother.o entryother
    $(OBJDUMP) -S bootblockother.o > entryother.asm
#
initcode: initcode.S
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -nostdinc -I. -c initcode.S
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e start -Ttext 0 -o initcode.out initcode.o
    $(OBJCOPY) -S -O binary initcode.out initcode
    $(OBJDUMP) -S initcode.o > initcode.asm

kernel: $(OBJS) entry.o entryother initcode kernel.ld
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -T kernel.ld -o kernel entry.o $(OBJS) -b binary initcode entryother
    $(OBJDUMP) -S kernel > kernel.asm
    $(OBJDUMP) -t kernel | sed '1,/SYMBOL TABLE/d; s/ .* / /; /^$$/d' > kernel.sym

# kernelmemfs is a copy of kernel that maintains the
# disk image in memory instead of writing to a disk.
# This is not so useful for testing persistent storage or
# exploring disk buffering implementations, but it is
# great for testing the kernel on real hardware without
# needing a scratch disk.

#MEMFSOBJS = $(filter-out ide.o,$(OBJS)) memide.o
#kernelmemfs: $(MEMFSOBJS) entry.o entryother initcode kernel.ld fs.img
#   $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -T kernel.ld -o kernelmemfs entry.o  $(MEMFSOBJS) -b binary initcode entryother fs.img
#   $(OBJDUMP) -S kernelmemfs > kernelmemfs.asm
#   $(OBJDUMP) -t kernelmemfs | sed '1,/SYMBOL TABLE/d; s/ .* / /; /^$$/d' > kernelmemfs.sym
#
#tags: $(OBJS) entryother.S _init
#   etags *.S *.c

vectors.S: vectors.pl
    ./vectors.pl > vectors.S

ULIB = ulib.o usys.o printf.o umalloc.o

#
_%: %.o $(ULIB)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e main -Ttext 0 -o $@ $^
    $(OBJDUMP) -S $@ > $*.asm
    $(OBJDUMP) -t $@ | sed '1,/SYMBOL TABLE/d; s/ .* / /; /^$$/d' > $*.sym

_forktest: forktest.o $(ULIB)
    # forktest has less library code linked in - needs to be small
    # in order to be able to max out the proc table.
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e main -Ttext 0 -o _forktest forktest.o ulib.o usys.o
    $(OBJDUMP) -S _forktest > forktest.asm

mkfs: mkfs.c fs.h
    gcc -Werror -Wall -o mkfs mkfs.c

# Prevent deletion of intermediate files, e.g. cat.o, after first build, so
# that disk image changes after first build are persistent until clean.  More
# details:
# http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html
.PRECIOUS: %.o

UPROGS=\
    _cat\
    _echo\
    _forktest\
    _grep\
    _init\
    _kill\
    _ln\
    _ls\
    _mkdir\
    _rm\
    _sh\
    _stressfs\
    _usertests\
    _wc\
    _zombie\
    _login\
    _cp\
    _head\
    _bedit\
    _clear\
    _tail\
    _sleep\
    _date\


fs.img: mkfs README $(UPROGS)
    ./mkfs fs.img README $(UPROGS) simple.txt

-include *.d

clean: 
    rm -f *.tex *.dvi *.idx *.aux *.log *.ind *.ilg \
    *.o *.d *.asm *.sym vectors.S bootblock entryother \
    initcode initcode.out kernel xv6.img fs.img kernelmemfs \
    xv6memfs.img mkfs .gdbinit \
    $(UPROGS)

# make a printout
FILES = $(shell grep -v '^\#' runoff.list)
PRINT = runoff.list runoff.spec README toc.hdr toc.ftr $(FILES)

#xv6.pdf: $(PRINT)
#   ./runoff
#   ls -l xv6.pdf

#print: xv6.pdf

# run in emulators

#bochs : fs.img xv6.img
#   if [ ! -e .bochsrc ]; then ln -s dot-bochsrc .bochsrc; fi
#   bochs -q

# try to generate a unique GDB port
GDBPORT = $(shell expr `id -u` % 5000 + 25000)
# QEMU's gdb stub command line changed in 0.11
QEMUGDB = $(shell if $(QEMU) -help | grep -q '^-gdb'; \
    then echo "-gdb tcp::$(GDBPORT)"; \
    else echo "-s -p $(GDBPORT)"; fi)
ifndef CPUS
CPUS := 2
endif
QEMUOPTS = -drive file=fs.img,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -drive file=xv6.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -smp $(CPUS) -m 512 $(QEMUEXTRA)

qemu: fs.img xv6.img
    $(QEMU) -serial mon:stdio $(QEMUOPTS)

#qemu-memfs: xv6memfs.img
#   $(QEMU) -drive file=xv6memfs.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -smp $(CPUS) -m 256

#qemu-nox: fs.img xv6.img
#   $(QEMU) -nographic $(QEMUOPTS)

#.gdbinit: .gdbinit.tmpl
#   sed "s/localhost:1234/localhost:$(GDBPORT)/" < $^ > $@

#qemu-gdb: fs.img xv6.img .gdbinit
#   @echo "*** Now run 'gdb'." 1>&2
#   $(QEMU) -serial mon:stdio $(QEMUOPTS) -S $(QEMUGDB)

#qemu-nox-gdb: fs.img xv6.img .gdbinit
#   @echo "*** Now run 'gdb'." 1>&2
#   $(QEMU) -nographic $(QEMUOPTS) -S $(QEMUGDB)

# CUT HERE
# prepare dist for students
# after running make dist, probably want to
# rename it to rev0 or rev1 or so on and then
# check in that version.

EXTRA=\
    mkfs.c ulib.c user.h cat.c echo.c forktest.c grep.c kill.c\
    ln.c ls.c mkdir.c rm.c stressfs.c usertests.c wc.c zombie.c\
    printf.c umalloc.c\
    README dot-bochsrc *.pl toc.* runoff runoff1 runoff.list\
    .gdbinit.tmpl gdbutil\

dist:
    rm -rf dist
    mkdir dist
    for i in $(FILES); \
    do \
        grep -v PAGEBREAK $$i >dist/$$i; \
    done
    sed '/CUT HERE/,$$d' Makefile >dist/Makefile
    echo >dist/runoff.spec
    cp $(EXTRA) dist

dist-test:
    rm -rf dist
    make dist
    rm -rf dist-test
    mkdir dist-test
    cp dist/* dist-test
    cd dist-test; $(MAKE) print
    cd dist-test; $(MAKE) bochs || true
    cd dist-test; $(MAKE) qemu

# update this rule (change rev#) when it is time to
# make a new revision.
#tar:
#   rm -rf /tmp/xv6
#   mkdir -p /tmp/xv6
#   cp dist/* dist/.gdbinit.tmpl /tmp/xv6
#   (cd /tmp; tar cf - xv6) | gzip >xv6-rev10.tar.gz  # the next one will be 10 (9/17)
#

.PHONY: dist-test dist
```

Edit:
what I want to do is put all my UPROGS programs into a directory called programs. How would i change the makefile to do so.

Comment: You will find a line in the Makefile starting with `fs.img:`. Below it follows the recipe for compiling it. What is unclear about this?

Comment: where does it say after fs.img: $(CC)

Comment: I can not see any cc commands

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear to you. To build `fs.img`, make runs the command `./mkfs fs.img README $(UPROGS) simple.txt`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, but was compiles the user programs. mkfs or gcc

Comment: The command says `mkfs`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 So does mkfs compile it then

Comment: I don't know what `mkfs` does.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have read the code. It does not look like a compiler

Comment: @mkrieger1 can you tell me which line compiles the user programs.

Comment: Presumably the lines following `_%:`, assuming that by "user programs" you mean `UPROGS`, and given that `UPROGS` lists program names starting with `_`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes. But how does it compile the c code for the uprogs. There is no list or anything for the c code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All make systems (as required by POSIX) have a number of built-in rules including rules that know how to compile object files from C files.

For information on GNU make's built-in rules you can [review the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html).

Comment: So how would a put all  user programs into a folder names programs. would i change the UPROGS variable.

Comment: That's one thing you have to do.  Then you'll have to tell make how to build that, because make has builtin rules that know how to build a program `foo` from a source file `foo.c` but it doesn't have any built-in rule that knows how to buld a program `programs/foo` from the source file `foo.c`.  So you'll have to write a pattern rule that tells make how to do that.

Comment: So I will need to make it compile all the files in the folder. Could you show an example please?

Comment: You want a pattern rule.  Information on writing pattern rules can be found in the manual here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html and there are examples there.  If you try to make it work and you can't, ask another question showing what you tried and how it didn't work and we'll help you figure out what's wrong.